# Reordering a list from comma sepperated ID's

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of objects I want to reorder. The order is determined in a string.

(I hope my current code explains better than the text)

```
List<DataObject> objects = GetDataObjectsFromDatabase();
string order = "1,3,2";
List<DataObject> orderedObjects = new List<DataObject>
foreach(string index in order.Split(',')
{
    orderedObjects.Add(objects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == index));
}
```

Is there a single Linq statement or a better way to do this?

Comment: For starters you can use `ToList()` instead of adding items to the list one by one. Perhaps `order.Split(',').Select(idx=>objects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == idx)).ToList()`

Comment: What is your criteria for "better"? Less code? More performant? More readable? Can you guarantee that your order string doesn't reference objects that are not there?

Comment: First of all, you should not keep order in string. I assume that you load it from somewhere and you may end up with "1, A, 2" which may result with error.

Comment: @MichałWoliński the string comes from a hidden input field. This is used for an interface where a user can drag and drop the DataObjects to order them. This is done in javascript which writes the order of the items to the hidden field.

Comment: @PatrickNijhuis have you tried the simple Split, Select? Do you want something more than that? You could modify the data access method to return a `Dictionary<string,DataObject>` to make ID lookup faster. If you use EF or EF Core all you'd need to do is add a call to `ToDictionary(item=>item.id,item=>item)` at the end instead of `ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of ordering list based on another list in linq:

```
        List<OBJ> Test = new List<OBJ>();
        Test.Add(new OBJ(1));
        Test.Add(new OBJ(2));
        string Order = "1,2,3";
        List<string> OrderBy = Order.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
        Test = Test.OrderBy(x => OrderBy.IndexOf(x.Field1.ToString())).ToList();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Assuming that x.Field1 is your ID (or whatever field you want to sort by).

Comment: `Split` returns an array so `ToList()` just allocates an extra object without any benefit. Using both `OrderBy` and `IndexOf` is expensive as `IndexOf` has to scan the entire list each time. Using `Split().ToLookup()` or `ToDictionary()` would actually improve performance

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `.Select()` will happen in order:

`var orderedObjects = order.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Select(index => objects.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.id == index).ToList();`

Comment: If order has 3 numbers and list has 2 output will have 3 elements (last will be null).

Answer (score -1):

var data = order.Split(',').ToList();

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that doesn't achieve my goal. This only produces a list.